# Error mounting university windows file server (mount error(13): Permission denied)

Tags: linux, mount, cifs

I am trying to mount my university's windows file server under linux. When I run `sudo mount -v -t cifs -o ro,username=****@***.ca,password=*** //server.cm.uni.ca/ /media/marcel/server`, I get the following output:

```
mount.cifs kernel mount options: ip=***.103.8.48,unc=\\server.cm.uni.ca\,user=***,pass=********
mount error(13): Permission denied
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I tried with and without the `ro` flag. Since it is a university server, the access is pretty limited. I only have read access. Is there anything else I can try before getting help from someone on campus?

`uname -a`:

```
Linux Hermes 4.9.11-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sun Feb 19 13:45:52 UTC 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can access the server just fine under windows with the same credentials.

Edit: I also tried mounting just one share: `//server.cm.uni.ca/share/`.

Comment: Can you use `sudo mount` on other Windows/Samba network file systems? Is `/media/marcel/server` a directory with full access for `root`? Does `/media/marcel` also have full root access? It looks more like a Linux configuration problem than anything to do with network permissions.

Comment: Without sudo I get `mount: only root can use "--options" option`. `/media`, and `/media/marcel`. All subfolders are owned by `root` and are 755. `marcel` is in `wheel`.

Comment: That's as expected: `mount` has only display options unless run as root. What about `/media/marcel/server`?